# Python - Tweet data(Json): How to filter out broken tweet? (the line is not in json format)

Tags: json, python-3.x, twitter

I am on the assignment to load the tweet data(JSON) into Python.
One of the tasks is to filter out the broken tweet(the line is not in JSON format)

My first code:

```
with open('./hw2-files-10mb.txt') as json_file:
data =json.load(json_file)

Output: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 3979)
```

I add in try/except and what I want the program to do is, when the line is not in JSON format, skip.filter the line and move on to load the next line.

```
with open('./hw2-files-10mb.txt') as json_file:
lines = json_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    try: 
        data =json.load(json_file)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

However, my output is only one tweet. It seems like the code stops running when an error occurs. Please advise. Thanks and have a nice weekend.